# LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR

Tags: php, mysql

Дело было так.

Удалена таблица, в которой были связи через FOREIGN KEY с другими таблицами.

Тепеь при создании таблицы с таким же именем возникает ошибка 150

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
180517 13:01:14 Error in foreign key constraint of table kpd_new/brands_lang:
there is no index in the table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
table do not match the ones in the referenced table
or one of the ON ... SET NULL columns is declared NOT NULL. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT "fk_brands_lang_langs1" FOREIGN KEY ("lang") REFERENCES "langs" ("code") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Как удалить этот fk_brands_lang_langs1 если при обращении нужна таблица, которую не возможно создать. Какой то замкнутый круг получается.

Comment: вы прочитали текст сообщения, который вам указан в ошибке? У вас приведено 3 причины этой ошибки, и последняя, очевидно, не подходит.

Comment: проблема была в том, что таблицы вообще не сущесвовало, а все 3 причины ссылаются на тадлицу. Получается, что ключ "повис" без таблицы

Comment: вам написано в сообщении об ошибке было, что в создаваемой таблице нет соответствующих столбцов, или у них не те типы данных.

Comment: спасибо, теперь все стало ясно )

Comment: Наверное некорректно задал вопрос. У меня был проблема не в поиске причины ошибки а в том как ее решить. Просто не понятно откуда msql знает какие нужны столбцы(или типы) для создания таблицы если таблица не создана (была удалена). Другие таблицы были никак не связаны с ней (все ключи были прописаны в ней до удаления).

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так:
Повторил структуру таблицы в точности так как была до удаления, но без связей foreignkey (просто поля) и таблица создалась, потом добавил связи.